# Laravel session is lost after changing folders

Tags: php, laravel

I don't know if this is even possible, but I will explain it to you. I am trying to verify user with SSLVerifyClient, but only if user chooses so (user can log in with email/password or with cert). I created another folder in the public directory called idportaal. In the folder I have my `.htaccess` file with `SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 2`, also an `index.php` and my functions file.

When user clicks on a link, I will point to idportal folder, where user is asked for certification: if valid certification is provided, I will log the user in manually and  trying to redirect the user to homepage but it does not work.

I can start laravel outside the laravel installation folder. I get the correct user, but as soon as I go to homepage, the session is unset. Is it possible to set the session?

Here's my code from idportal/index.php

```
<?php

require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel');

$response = $kernel->handle(
  $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

include "ocspcheck.php";

if (!$_SERVER["SSL_CLIENT_CERT"])
{
    echo "Couldn't get client SSL certificate (ID-card autentication certificate)!";
}
else
{
    $result = doOCSPcheck($_SERVER["SSL_CLIENT_CERT"]);

    // $app['session']->driver()->setId($id);
    // $app['session']->driver()->start();

    $userData = $_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN'];

    $first_name = $_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_G'];
    $last_name  = $_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_S'];

    //get the user with the name
    $selected_user = App\User::where('user_firstname', $first_name)->where('user_lastname', $last_name)->first();

    if (isset($_COOKIE[$app['config']['session.cookie']])) {
            //login user with the id
        $id = $app['encrypter']->decrypt($_COOKIE[$app['config']['session.cookie']]);
            //set session id
        $app['session']->driver()->setId($id);
    }
    //start session
    $app['session']->driver()->start();
    \Auth::loginUsingId($selected_user->id);
    //put user to session
    \Session::put('user', Auth::user());
    //save session
    \Session::save();
}
```

Link to the folder in login page

```
 <a href="/idportaal/idkaart/index.php"><img src="assets/login/id-kaart-logo.gif"></a>
```

Comment: It looks very unorthodox to do what you're doing. Typically you'd use a middleware for this.

Comment: @apokryfos any example how would I go with this?

Comment: You seems to creating a whole separate $app instance in this file.  I guess that's the reason as rest of the application works with a separate app instance.   It's like running two installations..

Comment: You are better creating a route/controller for doing this. I guess all you will have to do is create a route with anonymous function and move your code to that.

Comment: I tried that, but I cannot do it because then the whole site won't be reachable without SSLVerifyClient

Comment: @Ankit and if I don't include that line in the .htaccess then it won't ask for my certificate

Comment: I see. Ok then I would be taking a different approach. Instead of user login within this file after validating certificate, I would rather redirect user to one of the routes defined in the main app that will take care of user login and the it will automatically redirect to homepage.

Comment: @Ankit so I would still need an external folder for this?

Comment: yes. Do whatever you are doing.. But at the last where you log the user in, in this idportaal/index.php file. Don't do that. Instead create a new route say `/ssl/login_auto/ ` and redirect to this route. This route will first login the user using `Auth::login($user)` and then redirect to homepage. Obviously you'll need to pass something along to identify which user needs to be logged in. You may pass the id directly if you are not much worred about security. But if not then generate some number, save in db and pass it along when you redirect. Verify the same on `/ssl/login_auto/ ` .

Comment: I hope that makes sense

Comment: @Ankit it does actually make sense. I will try to create the route. Thanks man. you were really helpful to be honest! :D

Comment: @Ankit LOVE YOU MAN!

Comment: Glad to help. Just posted my comments as answer. Feel free to accept if that solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do what you are doing already. But at the last where you log the user in, in this `idportaal/index.php` file. Don't do that. Instead create a new route say /ssl/login_auto/ and redirect to this route. This route will first login the user using `Auth::login($user)` and then redirect to homepage. Obviously you'll need to pass something along to identify which user needs to be logged in. You may pass the id directly if you are not much worred about security. But if not then generate some number, save in db and pass it along when you redirect. Verify the same on `/ssl/login_auto/`